# Why does this circuit oscillate despite a short?

Tags: transistors, current, oscillator, inductor, short-circuit

I was following a tutorial online and found the following schematic:[image]

Here, there seems to be a base-emitter (and base-collector) short hence bypassing the transistor completely. I still constructed the circuit and to my surprise it does oscillate (it induces aa 10mA current in a secondary coil placed nearby). Why is this?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that the secondary coil also has a potential difference of 3 volts. This current remains as long as the circuit I'd connected to a power source

Comment: Where did the circuit come from?

Comment: @Andyaka This YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLu16Yd-c20 It is a Hartley oscillator

Comment: It's not a hartley oscillator if the base is shorted to the emitter.

Comment: @Andyaka, yes of course but it is meant to be one. This exactly is the problem- it's not a Hartley oscillator but is behaving like one!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like something was erased in the area containing the short. Perhaps it was another resistor to form a DC biasing circuit with R1.

Are you sure your secondary coil isn't picking up 50 Hz or 60 Hz interference from the mains?

Comment: No, It was a capacitor that was used for voltages higher than 10 V. I am operating this on a DC supply so interference isn't possible.

Comment: Why would you replace a capacitor for a short???? It should an open... that C2 that used to be in the schematic goes does as you decrease the voltage and it seems from the 3-6V range you get rid of it and the circuit ends up using the parasitic capacitance instead of C2.

Comment: @RandomUser What is the frequency of the oscillation? Mains interference is radiated by everything around you that's AC-powered. You don't have to plug your circuit into the wall to pick up interference. Also, does the oscillation last a long time, or does it die out?

Comment: I haven't been able to measure the frequency but considering that the current is almost 10 milliamps with a voltage of 3 volts it is certainly impossible that this is mains interference. The oscillation lasts a long time

Comment: Interesting. I thought the turn-on transient might produce temporary oscillation in the LC tank circuit, but it seems that's not the case. I'm out of ideas. Sorry!

Comment: @Kvegaoro sorry, I just saw your comment. I don't know, I didn't make the schematic but since there were two schematics (one for larger voltages and one for smaller) I compared them and that's how I know about the cap. In general use I certainly would remove the short but I wanted to see how it works (in theory it shouldn't have but in the video it did so I wanted to try)